# Trying to use GNU Parallel with sed

Tags: bash, scripts, sed, parallels

Why does this line do nothing? I'm trying to run a "sed" command in parallel and it outputs nothing to "standard.txt"

$Filetemp = the file I'm stream editing

standard.txt = the file I'm outputting to

```
cat $Filetemp | parallel --pipe sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" > standard.txt
```

---

This is the original code that works just fine but takes way too long:

```
sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" $Filetmp > standard.txt
```

---

GNU Parallel Version: 20130922

Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: What `parallel --pipe sed` command really does?

Comment: I have no idea how to use parallel so I don't know what works or doesn't

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Did you want to replace one or more spaces to a single space?

Comment: I would like to run `sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" $Filetmp > standard.txt` in parallel since the file I'm editing is huge.

Comment: Did the `$Filetmp` variable contains a single file or not?

Comment: Yes `$Filetemp` is one file.

Comment: `sed` parses the input line by line. I don't know the meaning of parallel.

Comment: Option -q http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#quoting If $Filetemp is a real file, then you may find the new option `--pipepart` interesting, too.

Answer (score 6):

When I run that on a random file, I got a syntax issue. You need to quote the command:

```
cat $Filetemp | parallel --pipe 'sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"' > standard.txt
```

If that still doesn't work for you, test `echo $Filetemp` (or pick a file manually) or remove the redirection so you can see the output as it happens (just in case there's some sort of weird overwriting issue).

Comment: Thanks, all I needed was the single quotes. Oddly enough it seems to run slower than running on one core. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 20140422 GNU Parallel has had `--pipepart` which is highly efficient:

```
parallel -a $Filetemp --pipepart 'sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"' > standard.txt
```

And from version 20161222 you can use `--block -1` which will chop `$Filetemp` into one block per jobslot:

```
parallel -a $Filetemp --block -1 --pipepart 'sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"' > standard.txt
```

This can deliver more than 1 GB/s for each core, which means your are likely limited by I/O. You can see if this the case by looking at:

```
iostats -dkx 1
```

If the utilization is 100%, then the disk is the bottleneck.